# Выбор индекса объекта в коллекции

Tags: javascript, коллекции, underscore.js

Каким образом эффективнее всего найти индекс объекта коллекции, который имеет указанное свойство. Например, нужно найти индекс объекта коллекции, который имеет свойство id равное 123.
Сейчас при помощи Underscore делаю так:

```
_.indexOf(collection, _.findWhere(collection, {id: 123}));
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, более красивый и эффективный способ, если таковой имеется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как в [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex), так и в [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#findIndex) есть метод `_.findIndex`, который собственно объединяет функционал `_.index` и `_.findWhere` и возвращает индекс элемента коллекции по условию:

```
var collection = [{id: 321}, {id: 123}, {id: 333}];

_.findIndex(collection, {id: 123}); // 1
```

В дополнение есть метод `findLastIndex`, который ищет с конца коллекции (в [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#findLastIndex) и [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#findLastIndex)).

**Обновление:**

В Underscore эти методы появились только с версии 1.8 (в Lodash - с 1.1.0)

Comment: Да, это именно то, что я и хотел. Знал, что теоретически этот метод должен был существовать, но так как пользовался русскоязычной версией сайта Underscore, то был обманут, там документация по версии 1.6, в которой нет этого метода :) Спасибо

Comment: Да, забыл отметить, что в Underscore этот метод появился только с версии 1.8 (в Lodash - с 1.1.0)

Answer (score 3):

С точки зрения функциональности, все отлично.

С точки зрения скорости, Lodash работает быстрее Underscore.
Вот пара тестов:

- Underscore (у меня около 60 мс): http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/amcfve44/
- Lodash (у меня около 40 мс): http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/L5pbdgqs/

Код теста:

```
var collection = [{id: 321}, {id: 123}, {id: 333}];

// warm up
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    var test = _.indexOf(collection, _.findWhere(collection, {id: 123}));
}

console.time('indexOF: ')
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    var test = _.indexOf(collection, _.findWhere(collection, {id: 123}));
}
console.timeEnd('indexOF: ')
```

Comment: Это разогрев, чтобы сгладить задержки при запуске.

Comment: @Regent, хех, вы правы